# Как отправить фотографию в бота телеграмм aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, бот, aiogram

Дело в том что есть генератор qr кода, он генерирует код сохраняет его в папку, но как сделать чтобы он отправлялся в сообщение боту

Answer (score 5):

Создайте объект `InputFile`, в котором хранится путь к файлу и воспользуйтесь методом `send_photo()`:

```py
photo = InputFile("files/test.png")

await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo)
```

Comment: а чем ваш ответ принципиально отличается от предыдущего ответа?

Comment: Мой ответ более соответствует фреймворку aiogram. Аргумент photo должен принимать объект InputFile.

Comment: Там происходит то что человек водит код который генерируется ,как сделать чтобы открывалось именно то фото которое до этого сгенерировалось с этим кодом

Comment: photo = InputFile(f'./data/tmp/emulator_{code}.png')

await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=photo)
Таким способом можно будет вывести

Comment: `InputFile(f'data/tmp/emulator_{code}.png') `

Answer (score 0):

Держи

```
photo = open('Путь к фото', 'rb')
await bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo)
```

Comment: Не понял, работает же

Comment: Про `with open ...` главное не забывать

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('Путь к фото', 'rb') as photo:
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно импортировать InputFile

```
from aiogram.types import InputFile
```

Затем создать переменную, через которую указываем путь к фото и указываем нашу переменную photo при отправке через bot.send_photo()

```
photo = InputFile("files/any_picture.png")

await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Покажу самый лёгкий путь. (aiogram v3.x >)

Если используеться Bot то:

```
await bot.send_photo(msg.chat.id, photo=types.FSInputFile(photo_path))
```

Если через Router то (@router.message):

```
await message.answer(reply)_photo(photo=types.FSInputFile(photo_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

aiogram 3.x
Мне такой способ помог.
Написал функцию

```
@router.message(F.photo)
async def get_photo(msg: Message):
    await msg.answer(f'ID фото: {msg.photo[-1].file_id}')
```

Дальше в бота в телеге отправил фото с компа, получил id
Дальше написал так

```
await bot.send_photo('-id канала', photo='id фото которое отдаст бот в предыдущей функции', 
caption='здесь какой то текст', reply_markup=инлайн_кнпока)
```

на этом все, бот отправляет сообщение в канал, снизу под постом кнопка для перехода на рекламируемый ресурс.