# Как сделать чтобы когда на входе загружались фото в виде документа, в другой чат бот пересылал их в виде обычных фото?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Я пишу бота на `python aiogram` , вопрос такой мне нужно сделать так чтобы когда пользователь загрузил боту фото в формате файла , то есть тип контента `document`, то в другой чат они приходили как обычные фотографии, так же в виде альбома.
Код следующий:

```
@dp.message_handler(is_media_group = True, content_types=content_types=types.ContentType.ANY, state=FSMAdmin.photo)
async def load_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext, album: List[types.Message]):
      """This handler will receive a complete album of any type."""
    media_group = types.MediaGroup()
    for obj in album:
        if obj.photo:
            file_id = obj.photo[-1].file_id
        else:
            file_id = obj[obj.content_type].file_id


        try:
            # We can also add a caption to each file by specifying `"caption": "text"`
            media_group.attach({"media": file_id, "type": obj.content_type})
        except ValueError:
            return await message.answer("This type of album is not supported by aiogram.")

    # await message.answer_media_group(media_group)
    await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=chat_id, media=media_group)
    print('Альбом отправлен в чат админов!')
```

На данный момент если отправить боту альбом фото в виде документов , то он просто отправит так же его в виде документа.
Можно ли сделать так чтобы он получал на входе документы с фото, а пересылал в виде простых фото.

В другом варианте моего обработчика, фото сначала сохраняются,  ну то есть документами в папку , но я боюсь что если брать из папки , то он будет присылать все фото за сегодня, а нужно только те что прислали в данный момент, может можно добавить какую-нибудь промежуточную папку чтобы он брал оттуда например `photos/сегодняшняя дата/промежуточная папка, которая меняется чтобы он не отправлял все фото за сегодня/documents/и тут фото` .
Код сохранения фото:

```
date = f"{datetime.date.today()}"
    if not album:
        album = [message]
    for obj in album:
        if obj.photo:
            path = os.path.join('photos', date)
            await obj.photo[-1].download(destination_dir=path)
            print('Фото сохранены на сервер!')
        else:
            path = os.path.join('photos', date)
            await obj[obj.content_type].download(destination_dir=path)
            print('Файлы сохранены на сервер!')
```

Можно ли как то это обыграть? Чтобы они одной группой, отправлялись в другой чат?

UPD1:
Я нашел такой [вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1301897/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC-aiogram), здесь используют `InputFile`, а так же вот такой [вариант](https://qna.habr.com/q/1034324) с использованием `Media.Group()` как можно их совместить чтобы все подходило под требования?

Comment: Нужно очень срочно

Comment: в целом данный вариант подходит, но можно ли реализовать чтобы фото присылались группой, а не по 1 фото ?
photo = with open(file_name, 'rb')
await bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo)
@oleksandrigo

Answer (score 0):

скорее всего, нужно поменять `ContentType` тут

```
media_group.attach({"media": file_id, "type": obj.content_type})
```

либо указав напрямую content_type `types.ContentTypes.PHOTO`, либо так (***псевдокод***)

```
if obj.content_type == 'DOCUMENT':
    cnt_type = types.ContentTypes.PHOTO
else:
    cnt_type = obj.content_type
 
media_group.attach({"media": file_id, "type": cnt_type})
```

---

#UPD

немного узнав подробнее, могу предложить просто заменить ваш метод `.attach()` на следующее

```
media_group.attach({"media": file_id, "type": "photo"})
```

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: я переименовал cnt_type в file_id и подставил ваш способ
он поругался выдав в логи это:

Comment: `aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Field "media" must be of type string`

Comment: Я что то не так сделал мне кажется

Comment: тут уже дело в самом file_id, попробуй его заприптить и проверить его тип

Comment: попробовал подставить еще content_type по вашему ответу и выдало следующее:
`TypeError: Invalid media type '['photo']'!`

Comment: это был псевдокод, я увы не знаю в каком именно формате у вас там хранятся данные
распечатайте сам obj.content_type и посмотрите какого он типа, и уже под него можно подгонять остальное

Comment: я распечатал и он вывел `document`

Comment: тогда самое верное что вам нужно, указывать сразу как я и говорил тип
`"type": "photo"` и всё

Comment: Сможете расписать в ответе?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138975/discussion-between-alex-and-st0rm1k).