# Отправка изображения в телеграм боте с помощью aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, изображения, aiogram

Пишу бота с помощью aiogram. Планируется создать словарь, в котором будут храниться различные изображения. Один ключ - одно изображение. В боте есть функция, числовой результат которой и будет индексом ключа. Помогите реализовать функционал выдачи пользователю бота необходимого изображения из словаря.

Comment: Я вас не понимаю. Вы не умеете получать значение из словаря или не умеете отправлять фото? Если первое то вам нужно заново учить питон, если второе то достаточно написать в гугле [как отправить фото aiogram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1301905/312230) и вы получите ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Непонятный вопрос. Может тебе что-то по типу такого нужно?

Пишешь хендлер для текста, инструкцию с функцией и дальше:

```
if message.text == "026": 
       photo = open('папка\изображение1.png','rb') #картинка из твоей базы
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
if message.text == "021": 
       photo = open('папка\изображение2.png','rb') #другая картинка из твоей базы
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
```

Либо понятнее объясни желаемое.

Comment: Зачем здесь `IF`ы и дублирование кода, если в вопросе речь шла про словарь с изображениями?