# Как на Aiogram отправлять фотографию?

Tags: python, aiogram

Допустим,если ввести команду в личной странице бота /photo, то он отправит конкретную фотографию с текстом?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отправить фотографию в бота телеграмм aiogram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1301897/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc-aiogram)

Answer (score 1):

Что б отправить фото нужно использовать метод send_photo(). InputFile() это объект в котором укаказываем путь к фото.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import InputFile

bot = Bot(token="TOKEN")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['photo'])
async def get_photo(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=InputFile('1.jpg'), caption="Text")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: @user531461 у меня выдает это:
   line 40, in __init__
    self._file = open(path_or_bytesio, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.jpeg'

Answer (score 0):

В 3 версии

```
from aiogram.types import FSInputFile
        # Отправка фото
@dp.message(Command('photo'))
async def get_photo(message: types.Message):
        await message.answer_photo(photo=FSInputFile('media/1.jpg', filename='Снеговик'), caption='Это снеговик!')
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].